# Perl Selenium::Remote::Driver test to check button element is formed?

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to test web site where button is formed at the bottom of the page after
user scroll the page for two times.

I have written a small script to test if the required element is formed.
the condition tested always return false even though required element is formed in the page.

```
 use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
 use Scalar::Util qw/blessed reftype/;

 my $driver= Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
 $driver->get('http://www.foo.com');

 while ( 1 ) {

     $query = $driver->find_element_by_xpath(q{//button[@class='button']});

     #to test the if the element is present
     if ( blessed($query) && $query->isa('Selenium::Remote::Driver') ) {

           $query->click;
           last;
     }
     else {

         #always goes into else loop
         #to go to the end of the webpage 
         my $script = q{window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);};
         my $elem = $driver->execute_script($script);
     }
 }
```

Is there any way to test if the button element has been formed in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below to find the element

```
my $elem = $driver->find_element_by_xpath($locator);
```

If this doesn't return 0 you've found your element, then you could run below:

To check whether the element is displayed

```
$elem->is_displayed();
```

To check whether the element is hidden

```
 $elem->is_hidden();
```

Check out more methods at: https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::WebElement

Answer (score 0):

All these function return 0 when element is not found.

[Read the doc carefully.](http://search.cpan.org/~gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.25/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm#find_element)

find_element_by_xpath

```
These functions all take a single STRING argument: the locator
search target of the element you want. If the element is found, we
will receive a WebElement. Otherwise, we will return 0. Note that
invoking methods on 0 will of course kill your script.
```